# Using Natural Log solve for x in (1/16)^(3x+1) = (1/18)^(x+1)

Tags: calculus

How do you use natural log to solve for x?

i really have no clue!

Answer (score 3):

$$(1/16)^{3x+1} = (1/18)^{x+1}$$
Take the natural log on both sides; we will get 
$$\ln 16^{-3x-1}=\ln 18^{-x-1}.$$
Using the properties for $\ln$, we have
$$(-3x-1) \ln 16 = (-x-1) \ln 18.$$
It is easy to solve for $x$ now.
Good luck!

Comment: easy for you! but would it be (-3x-1)/(-x-1) = ln 18/ln16 ? or is that illegal?

Comment: yaya...it is true...continue from here (-3x-1)/(-x-1) = ln 18/ln16, you will get the answer...All the best!

Comment: Welcome! You may find this [guide to formatting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) with MathJax to be useful. I've edited your post to include the formatting.

Comment: Thanks T.Bongers edit my answer nicely...^_^

Comment: @measure2012 how do you simplify (-3x-1)/(-x-1)?

Comment: Using long division, we will get -3-4/(x-1)...

Answer (score 0):

Lets continue from measure2012's answer (you don't really need long division). Define $a = \mathrm{ln} 16$ and $b = \mathrm{ln} 18$. Then the following are equivalent.

1. Your original equation.
2. $(−3x−1)a=(−x−1)b.$ $\;\;$ [By measure2012's work].
3. $-3ax-a  = -bx-b$
4. $bx-3ax = -b+a$.
5. $(b-3a)x = -b+a$
6. $x = \dfrac{b - 3a}{-b+a}$

If you want to eliminate $b$ and $a$ in this final answer, you can do that by replacing them with $\mathrm{ln} 16$ and $\mathrm{18}$. However, its probably a bit pointless.